$1-$Lipschitz function of two variables as limit of separable functions
Let $X,Y$ be compact metric spaces. Suppose $m: X \times Y \to [0,1]$ is $1-$Lipschitz, where $X \times Y$ is given the taxicab metric $d((x,y),(x',y'))=d_X(x,x')+d_Y(y,y')$. Can one write $m$ as a limit of $1-$Lipschitz functions $m_n$ such that $m_n$ is a convex combination of $1-$Lipschitz  functions of the form $h \cdot k$, with $h :X \to [0,1]$ and $k:Y \to [0,1]$ both $1-$Lipschitz?
It is clear that $m$ can be written as a limit of linear combinations of products of Lipschitz functions, by Stone-Weierstrass and the density of Lipschitz functions. It is also clear that the limit of the Lipschitz constants of such a sequence must converge to $1$. It is clear that such a sequence can be picked so that they are $[0,1]$ valued functions, although this doesn't imply that they a convex combination. I cannot see whether you can argue from that that it is sufficient to restrict to a sequence of $1$-Lipschitz functions, and whether you can restrict to convex combinations. I would also be interested if its instead possible to restrict to linear combinations $\sum_i \lambda_i h_i \cdot k_i$ with $\sum_i |\lambda_i| \leq 1$
If this result were true, it would in particular allow you to calculate the Kantorovich distance between joint probability measures using a supremum over a smaller class of 1-Lipschitz functions, and this is my motivation.

Can any of the people who have voted to close explain why?

While I did not vote to close, it is probably because you do not show any attempt and you have not yet enough reputation for people to ignore this :)

How the sequence $(m_n)$ shoud converge to $m$ (for instance, uniformly or pointwise)?

We shall show that even a pointwise limit for $m$ can fail to exist. For this purpose we shall need the following
Lemma. Let $a,a',b',b'\in [0,1]$, $|a'-a|\le 1/2$ and $|b'-b|\le 1/2$. Then $a'b'-ab\le 3/4$.
Proof. We can suppose that $a'\ge a$ because otherwise
$$a'b'-ab\le a'b'-a'b=a'(b'-b)\le 1\cdot 1/2=1/2.$$
Similarly we can suppose that $b'\ge b$. Then increasing $a'$ or $b'$ or decreasing $a$ or $b$ we can ensure that $a+1/2=a'\le 1$ and $b+1/2=b'\le 1$. Then $a'b'-ab=a/2+b/2+1/4\le 3/4$. $\square$
Let both $X$ and $Y$ be the interval $[0,1/2]$ and both $d_X$ and $d_Y$ be the usual metric. For each $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ put $m(x,y)=x+y$. Then the function $m:X\times Y\to [0,1]$ is $1$-Lipschitz and $m(1/2,1/2)-m(0,0)=1$.
On the other hand, let $n$ be any natural number, and for each natural $i\le n$ let $\lambda_i\ge 0$
and $h_i,k_i$ be $1$-Lipschitz functions from $[0,1/2]$ to $[0,1]$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i=1$.
Let $m'(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i h_i(x)k_i(y)$ for each $(x,y)\in X\times Y$.
Then using Lemma we obtain
$$m'(1/2,1/2)-m'(0,0)=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i h_i(1/2)k_i(1/2)-\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i h_i(0)k_i(0)=$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i (h_i(1/2)k_i(1/2)-h_i(0)k_i(0))\le \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i\cdot 3/4=3/4.\square$$

Nice example, thanks.
